# How to check if command were done?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I'am trying to do some stuff with git. I wonder how would I make the **if statement** argument to check if that command were done correctly:

```
git checkout master && git reset --hard && git fetch && git pull
```

I was trying with check if output is equal to if statement but I guess it's a bad idea. Here is a code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import subprocess
import time

while True:

x = subprocess.getoutput("git checkout master && git reset --hard && git fetch && git pull")

   if x is "Some text":
    print('Some actions there')

time.sleep(3600)
```

So I wonder is there any way to check if command where done or not.

Comment: just read about exit codes

Comment: Use [`.getstatusoutput()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) instead and check that the exit code is 0 (ie. successful).

Comment: I did 
x = subprocess.getstatusoutput("git checkout master && git reset --hard && git fetch && git pull")
    if x[0] is 0:
        print('do some stuff')
    time.sleep(2)
Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, but execute each of your command with [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) or [run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). I would recommend the latter, as its returned type has useful [check_returncode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.check_returncode) method. Use [shlex.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to turn command into list of its parts.

Basically what you want to do is something like:

```
import subprocess, shlex
for (cmd in ("git checkout master", "git reset --hard", "git fetch", "git pull")):
    subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd)).check_returncode()
```

Disclaimer: this was written ad-hoc and not tested. It is only supposed to show you how to get there, not do that for you all the way.